# I want to distribute points on the intersection of two objects using Geometry Nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I want to specifically distribute points on or near the intersection line of two objects.

This is the quick sketch I came up with. the annotation is where the points should be distributed. the plane is the object which will have the geometry nodes applied.

[image: Sketch of where the points should be distributed]

I thought about using dynamic paint and masks, but they are too resource intensive or too much manual work for what I am trying to achieve.

I used a Ray Cast node in the following image and got pretty close, but I do not want the points to be inside the object, just around the edges.

[image]

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Edit N1:

I managed to "brute force" the point distribution with 5 Ray Cast nodes, but this is way less then perfect. If I change the location of the cube sometimes the side point distribution nodes on the one or more sides are missing. So if anyone has a better way to do this I would really appriciate it. [image][image][image]

Comment: Perhaps the `Mesh Boolean` node would be of interest here? This provides you with the information on which edge the two objects intersect, and you could continue working with this information.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the result I was looking for by using a *Mesh Boolean* node and converting it into a curve:

[image]